Error in lmerTest: The random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
I know that there have been similar questions before, but I dont still get it.
I would like to estimate a multilevel model with repeated measures in R using the package “lmerTest”.  The model structure is as follows:

Level 1 represents the measurements (2 measurements per participant) and Level 2 the participants of the study. This means that there should be twice as many observations as there are unique IDs. Here ist the original (sligthly adapted) dataset:
structure(list(ID= c(41, 43, 44, 45, 61, 62, 63, 64, 
66, 68, 69, 71, 41, 43, 44, 45, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 68, 69, 71, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 32, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 32), 
    rating = c(4.12, 4.37, 4.32, 4.28, 3.23, 3.57, 3.78, 4.5, 
    3.55, 3.58, 4.27, 3.9, 4.55, 3.95, 3.78, 4.07, 2.92, 3.18, 
    4.03, 4.33, 3.93, 3.87, 4.38, 3.7, 4.63, 3.67, 3.43, 4.38, 
    4.57, 4.05, 4.13, 4.08, 3.78, 3.47, 3.55, 4.2, 3.43, 4.02, 
    2.4, 4.27, 3.18, 4.07, 3.62, 3.43, 3.83, 3.78, 4.8, 4.37, 
    4.08, 3.67, 3.58, 3.43, 4.03, 3.3, 3.57, 2.75, 4.52, 2.87
    ), measurement_time= c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
    "-1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), condition= c("0.5", "0.5", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", 
    "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", 
    "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", 
    "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", 
    "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5", "-0.5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-58L), class = "data.frame")

"ID" is the ID-variable and "rating" is the independent variable. The variable “measurement_time” is the effect coded level 1 predictor (X) and “condition” is the level 2 predictor Z (contrast coded).
Instead of running a mixed ANOVA, I estimated the following multilevel model (random intercept, random slope), since I learned in university, that this is the better more general approach:
model <- lmer(rating ~ 1 + measurement_time + condition + measurement_time*condition + 
   (1 + measurement_time|ID),data=data_filtered)

Now I got the following error:

number of observations (=58) <= number of random effects (=58) for term (1 + measurement_time| ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

I have the feeling that I have a basic lack of understanding of the identifiability of random variables. I am aware of the fact, that the sample is very small, but I want to calculate it nevertheless, cause it is a pilot study. I also wonder, if it would help at all, if there were more participants, because the number of random effects that have to be estimated seems to be identical to the number of observations.

Is your real data similar to this in the sense that you have most (> 75%) of the outcome variance at the ID level? That could be a contributing to the issues. I think you are asking too much from what is a very modest dataset. Eliminating the random slope is probably the way to go and/or collect more data. Sorry for the bad news.

@Erik the ICC of the original data ist around 76 %. But I still don't understand, why more observations would help. I would still have only two measurements per participant.

Generally speaking, having more timepoints of data can help you in differentiating trends across clusters (individuals) and potentially increase within cluster variability. Having more individuals gives you more opportunities to observe both within and between person variability in the outcome. At this point, 3/4 of the variability in your outcome is between persons. Maybe that is true in the population, but it could also be sample specific. More data would help you understand this.

This helps a lot. Do you have any recomandation for literature on this problem that I can quote?

This will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465215/random-slope-for-time-in-subject-not-working-in-lme4
